# Shell Command to convert strings to C printf statements

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file  "Hi.text" which looks like

```
valid = 0;
invalid = 0;
stats = 0;
inner_ufd = 0;
....
....
```

I would like to change the format of the contents of the hi.text file to

```
printf ( "valid       = %x", hi->valid );
printf ( "invalid     = %x", hi->invalid );
printf ( "stats       = %x", hi->stats );
.....
.....
.....
```

I tried several awk commands but none seems to work.Please suggest a way to convert hi.txt to the desired output.All of them are same size "int" 4 bytes . I just want the hi.txt to be formatted as the desired output. I am going to copy past the desired text format to my C program

Comment: Collect the values and max length, and then in `END` output everything.

Comment: all of them are same size "int" 4 bytes . I just want the hi.txt to be formatted as the desired output. I am going to copy past the desired text format to my C program.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your sourcefile is `so.txt`:

```
$ awk '{ print "printf ( \""$1"       = %x\", hi->"$1");" }' so.txt 
printf ( "valid       = %x", hi->valid);
printf ( "invalid       = %x", hi->invalid);
printf ( "stats       = %x", hi->stats);
printf ( "inner_ufd       = %x", hi->inner_ufd);
```

Using printf, you can get a cleaner view:

```
awk '{ printf "printf ( \"%-10s       = %%x\", hi->%s);\n", $1, $1 }' so.txt 
printf ( "valid            = %x", hi->valid);
printf ( "invalid          = %x", hi->invalid);
printf ( "stats            = %x", hi->stats);
printf ( "inner_ufd        = %x", hi->inner_ufd);
```

And finally, to edit inplace, you can use the `-i inplace` argument.

```
awk -i inplace '{ printf "printf ( \"%-10s       = %%x\", hi->%s);\n", $1, $1 }'  so.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But All printf statements displays "valid" field . I would like to have printf ( "invalid     = %x", hi->invalid );
printf ( "stats       = %x", hi->stats );

Comment: oops. Corrected.

Comment: You should mention that `-i inplace` is GNU awk only.